# Customise the error response when invalid JSON data is submitted

Tags: python, json, http, flask, curl

I am sending an invalid JSON that contains just `{` to my Flask app that validates the JSON and returns its result.

I got the following error by submitting the command through cURL.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @/Users/xxxx/yyyy/test.json http://0.0.0.0:5000/validate
```

```
HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 221
Server: Werkzeug/0.16.0 Python/3.7.3
Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2020 11:09:48 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)</p>
```

Normally, if the data is a valid JSON then there is a response from the server, but in this case, it seems that the app didn't make any reaction.

My questions are

- What exactly returns this message?
- Is it possible to customise the response? I'd like to customise the message in particular.

Comment: can you share with us the code of validate function ?

Comment: @cizario Is this a code matter? I think the app didn’t get any request by the invalid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to customize the error returned upon submitting an invalid json object, you can do like following :

```
from flask import jsonify, request
from werkzeug.wrappers import BaseRequest
[..]

@app.route('/validate')
def validate():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Assert that the payload is a valid JSON
        try:
            data = request.json
        except BadRequest, e:
            return jsonify(code=e.code,
                           name=e.name,
                           description=e.description), e.code
            # you can customize "description" message with your own like "Payload is not a valide JSON"

        # the payload is valid JSON
        # put your logic here ..
```

to read more how to customize application errors refer to:

- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#application-errors
- https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/exceptions/